# How to translate ImageMagick command to Imagick in PHP?

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I've tried to translate it, but doesn't work, doesn't anyone know what the wrong is ?

**ImageMagick**

```
convert source.jpg \( -size 640x480 xc:white -size 200x200 
xc:black -geometry +200+100 -compose over -composite \) 
+geometry -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite result.png
```

**PHP code with Imagick I tried, but didn't work:**

```
//Open your image and get its dimensions
$image = new Imagick('source.png');
$height = $image->getImageHeight();
$width = $image->getImageWidth();

//Create a new transparent image of the same size
$mask = new Imagick();
$mask->newImage($width, $height, new ImagickPixel('white'));

//Draw onto the new image the areas you want to be transparent in the original
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$draw->setFillColor('black'); 
$draw->rectangle($x, $y, $x + 200, $y + 200);
$mask->drawImage( $draw );

//Composite the images
$image->compositeImage($mask, Imagick::COMPOSITE_COPYOPACITY, 0, 0, Imagick::CHANNEL_ALPHA);
$image->setImageFormat('png');
$image->writeImage("~/images/result.png");
```

**Original Question:**

[How to make specified area of an image transparent with Imagick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46970937/how-to-make-specified-area-of-an-image-transparent-with-imagick)

**Another trying**

```
$width = 256;
$height = 256;
$x = 50;
$y = 100;
$fooWidth = 100;
$fooHeight = 60;


$image = new Imagick();
$image->newImage($width, $height, new ImagickPixel('yellow'));


//Create a new transparent image of the same size
$mask = new Imagick();
$mask->newImage($width, $height, new ImagickPixel('white'));
$mask->setImageFormat('png');

//Draw onto the new image the areas you want to be transparent in the original
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$draw->setFillColor('black');
$draw->rectangle($x, $y, $x + $fooWidth, $y + $fooHeight);
$mask->drawImage($draw);

//Composite the images
$image->compositeImage($mask, Imagick::COMPOSITE_COPYOPACITY, 0, 0);

$image->setImageFormat('png');
$image->writeImage($path);
```

**`COMPOSITE_COPYOPACITY` looks doesn't work:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try turning alpha off at the end when you create the mask. This works fine for me:

```
convert -size 500x500 xc:yellow \( -size 500x500 xc:white -fill black -draw "rectangle 100,100 300,300" -alpha off \) -compose copy_opacity -composite result.png
```

[image]

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimagematte.php where the example adds

```
$mask->setImageMatte(false);
```

After the draw command and before the compositeImage() command

Comment: Unbelievable, it works, how can I thank you for taking so much time to help me, I very very appreciate it :)

Comment: `@Suge` Glad to hear that it helped.

Answer (score 1):

First, you are drawing a rectangle with the same coordinates. You need to make them different to get a rectangle.

```
$draw->rectangle( 200, 100, 200, 100 );
```

Should be more like

```
 $draw->rectangle( 100, 100, 200, 200 )
```

This will draw a rectangle at top left of 100,100 and bottom right of 200,200. So the rectangle will be 100x100 in size.

If you want it to be like my command line example, then do

```
$draw->rectangle( 200, 100, 400, 300 );
```

That would be top left of 200,100 and bottom right of 400,300 so 200x200 size.

Second, you have not specified an output format. If you are writing to JPG, it does not support transparency. So be sure to use PNG or TIF for the output.

Comment: Thank you, I made a mistake at `rectangle`, I've corrected it, but it still doesn't work. Is it right to use `Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_DEACTIVATE` as the last parameter of `compositeImage `?

Comment: No that would remove the alpha channel. Sorry, I did not scroll enough to see that. I don't use Imagick, so I do not know what to tell you for that argument. From the Imagick docs, I would suggest you either leave it off to take the default or set it to CHANNEL_ALL

Comment: But you see, there is `-alpha off` in the `ImageMagick` command, I've tested `-alpha on`, the result won't be right as `-alpha off`, so I tried `Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_DEACTIVATE` even other options, but doesn't work all.

Comment: ImageMagick command line needs the -alpha off to be sure that neither image nor mask have an alpha channel. I don't know Imagick, but suspect you do not need that. Did you try leaving that parameter out or set it to CHANNEL_ALL as I suggested? If so, did it work?  Also I do not see where you specified $path

Comment: See the last example here http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.compositeimage.php. They left off the last argument.

Comment: Thank you @fmw42, I found that, no matter using what option for the last parameter,  if we use `COMPOSITE_COPYOPACITY`, there will be no effect at all. Meanwhile, `COMPOSITE_DSTOUT` made something different.  Pls see the post updated. and take a look back to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46970937/how-to-make-specified-area-of-an-image-transparent-with-imagick

Comment: Your code above does not show how you got $path. It is also missing: `header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $img1;` from that example

Comment: What version of ImageMagick and what version of Imagick and what platform?

Comment: The `$path` maybe something like '~/images/result.png', `ImageMagick` version is  `6.7.8-9`, platform is `Centos/Linux 7.0`, I didn't find version of `Imagick`.